# iis 7 deploying a new build of an existing site

Tags: iis-7

I would like to automate the process of deploying a new build of an existing site and allow for me to go back to the previous version of the site easily.   Up until this point I have been copying my new build to the production server and placing it into a folder with a build number associated with it.  Through the IIS user interface I would stop the site and then change the physical path on the site pointing it to my new build.  If for some reason I would need to back the changes out I would simply go back into IIS and stop the site and point it back to the previous build.

I see where I can use appcmd to stop and start the site.  I just can't find any way to change the physical path property on the site.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use powershell [Intro to Power Shell for IIS7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/161/an-introduction-to-windows-power-shell-and-iis7/)

EDIT: [This Page](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/) has examples for creating websites and applications in IIS with powershell.

Based on the samples it should be something like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\sites\DemoSite\DemoApp -physicalPath C:\DemoSite\DemoApp -type Application
```